# How to limit results obtained by hibernate criteria API?

Tags: java, hibernate

Let's suppose we have a Person class that is a simple hibernate entity. We have a DAO that has a method which retrieves all Person rows that have names listed in names list:

```
@Transactional
public List<Person> getPersons(List<String> personNames) {

ArrayList<Criterion> locationCriterions = new ArrayList<Criterion>();

if(personNames == null) {
       return new ArrayList<Person>();
}

Criterion [] arrayOfPersonCriterions = new Criterion 
[personNames.size()];

   int currentIndex = 0;

   for(String currentPersonName : personNames) {   
   arrayOfPersonCriterions[currentIndex](Restrictions.eq("name", 
   currentPersonName));
   currentIndex++;
   }     

   Criterion personFinalCriterion = Restrictions.or(arrayOfPersonCriterions);
   Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
   Criteria criteria = currentSession.createCriteria(Person.class);

   return (List<Person>)criteria.add(personFinalCriterion).list();

}
```

Question: How can I limit the amount of retrieved results - as in SQL where we can use LIMIT X, Y query text?

Please note:

- I want to use Criteria API and avoid native queries - I can use native queries but do not want to get rid of Criteria in general,
- avoid processing returned list so that it returns only range of results which I think is meaningless and not efficient.

Comment: A quick look at the Javadocs for Criteria and you'd have seen [this method](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#setMaxResults(int)) that does exactly what you're looking for...

Comment: Please I want to paginate the result not only see X first result !!!

Comment: And the documentation for `setFirstResult(int)`, which when used with `setMaxResults(int)` gives you pagination *is literally the next method down* from `setMaxResults(int)` in the Javadocs.

Comment: That is true, however your question also demonstrates a lack of research effort on your part. What does the downvote arrow's tooltip say? "**This question does not show any research effort;** it is unclear or not useful".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two methods of the `Criteria`

`criteria.setFirstResult(indexOfTheFirstRecord)` to specify the first record (started from **0**) 
`criteria.setMaxResults(numberOfTheRecords)` to specify count of the records

For simplicity you can use this class

```
public class Pagination {

    public static final Pagination EMPTY = new Pagination(0, 0);

    /** Page index, begins from 0. */
    private final int pageIndex;

    /** Objects on page count. */
    private final int pageSize;

    public Pagination(int pageIndex, int pageSize) {
        this.pageIndex = pageIndex;
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
    }

    public void addToCriteria(Criteria criteria) {
        if (this == EMPTY) {
            return;
        }
        criteria.setMaxResults(pageSize);
        criteria.setFirstResult(pageIndex * pageSize);
    }

}
```

**Example**

To get the second page (`pageIndex = 1`) with size 10 (records with `startIndex = 10`, `endIndex = 19`)

```
final int pageIndex = 1;
Pagination pagination = new Pagination(pageIndex, 10);
pagination.addToCriteria(criteria);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set use `setFirstResult` to skip the records and `setMaxResults` to fetch the number of records from that point.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Foo.class);
criteria.setFirstResult(0);
criteria.setMaxResults(pageSize);
List<Foo> firstPage = criteria.list();
```